# Sencha Touch 2.3 - Linking a container's height or minheight to a global sass variable

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

Is it possible to somehow link the minheight config of a Dataview (or any view for that matter) to a global variable

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-minHeight

E.g. I want to set this attribute = $height_of_element_contained*2 (where this variable has been defined inside the app.scss file)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class as `singleton` which contains your global variable in a field.
Once you have your global variable, at initialization of your view (in your controller for example) set your `minHeight` to be this global variable.

EDIT (examples) :

**Global sass variable :**

```
$myVar : 10px;
.myClass {
    min-height : $myVar !important;
}
```

**Global JS variable :**

*Singleton :*

```
Ext.define('myClass', {
    singleton : true,
    constructor : function(config) {
        this.globVar= '10px';
    }
});
```

*Static :*

```
Ext.define('myClass', {
    statics : {
        globVar : '10px';
    }
});
```

Depending on what you plan to do with your global variable, you should use one of the above.

-The sass solution is only if you plan on using this var for styling purpose. (what seems to be your case)

-The JS singleton is for storing variables that are used at many places in the JS code.

-The JS static is for variables that are specific to a class.

Note that if it is just to store a variable to set your min height, you should put it in your sass file, to separate content and style.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have an example - I don't understand logically why I need to refer this variable by putting it in a class, and not refer a css global variable directly. Is this part of the extjs architecture?

Comment: If you want to use your variable in your sass only, you can define it as a global variable with `$var = 5px;` and use it in your sass file. If you want to use it in javascript, you have to define it somewhere, might it be in a static wrapper of a class, or a singleton (the latter centralize the global resources and is easier to maintain.
I'll add some example in my answer